# Use SD or USB boot if OTP set

Tags: boot

If I set up to boot a pi3 from usb can I revert to sd slot boot later? This is in reference to the new OTP bit procedure

Comment: What new OTP procedure?

Comment: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=29&t=159691

Comment: The link is about the One Time Programmable Memory in the boot code of the Pi3 that allows USB drive to boot at power on. The link seems to imply that the boot will look for the slot, then check OTP bit  and boot from USB device. Google raspi otp

Answer (score 1):

[From Raspberry Pi Documentation:](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/raspberrypi/bootmodes/bootflow.md)

"The flow of boot begins with reading the OTP to decide on the valid boot modes enabled. By default, this is SD card boot followed by USB device boot. Subsequently, the boot ROM checks to see if the GPIO boot mode OTP bits have been programmed — one to enable GPIO boot mode and one to select the bank of GPIOs it uses to disable boot modes (low = GPIOs 22-26, high = GPIOs 39-43). This makes it possible to use a hardware switch to choose between different boot modes if there is more than one available."

As per above, it doesn't seem that you need to program the OTP (One Time Programmable) bits to boot from USB.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you do not need to *"revert"* from anything. The SD / TF slot will be still functioning as usual.

The OTP procedure will allow other boot options ( read: USB ) but it is `AND`, not `OR`.

SoC checks `bootcode.bin` on the SD card first. If not find proceed to USB.

So basically just taking out the USB and putting a TF in the slot will make the pi boot as usual.